# Convert each letter of string into ascii values - java

Tags: java, string, ascii

I want to add two strings and remove duplicate characters of the string then I want to convert each letter of the string into ascii values. After converting, I want to add each letter ascii values and get a total amount of the values..
for ex:

```
ab+ab 
ab // remove duplicates
65+66 //add ascii values
131 // total ascii values
```

Comment: post your attempts..

Comment: Please share what code you have already tried.

Comment: Post the code u tried..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well adding two Strings is simply concatenation using the + operator:

```
//first and second should be declared as String.
String both = first + second;
```

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157378/removing-duplicate-characters-in-a-string-user-inputted-keyword) to see how to remove duplicate characters from a String.

Lastly, the ascii value of a character is just the int value of that character. Because of this you can just do this:

```
int asciiSum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < both.length(); i++){
    asciiSum += (int)both.charAt(i);
}
```

That will give you the sum of the ascii values in your String.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @BearNithi is the error in removing duplicate characters?